# What does " i , j <-- 1"mean in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm trying to understand what this pseudocode does and I can't seem to understand what the comma is suppose to do here.

I know that `j <- 1` is `j = 1` but what about the `i`? And what does `j <- j` do in this case?

```
 fib iter(n) 
    i,j ← 1 
      for k ← 1 to n−1 
      i,j ← j,i + j 
    return j
```

Comment: It means whatever the author of that pseudocode has defined it to mean. The author of that pseudocode is the only person who can tell you that.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think this is actually actual code. I'm blanking on the programming language, but I'm pretty sure I've worked with this syntax before... though having said that, I'm now reminded of a professor I had in college who wrote his psuedocode in SmallTalk, but when I tried to talk with him about SmallTalk, he claimed ignorance. A week later he thanked me for introducing him to a language that worked so much like how he thought. So I suppose it could be both valid code and pseudocode.

Comment: @JörgWMittag While that's technically true, we can make a pretty good guess from circumstantial evidence here: the inclusion of the word "fib", and the fact that reading it a certain way would result in a generator of Fibonacci sequences *could* just be coincidence, I suppose.

Comment: @IMSoP: We can *assume*, for example, that `i,j ← 1` means parallel assignment. But, there are essentially two ways to interpret this: either `i` is assigned `1` and `j` is assigned `null` (or whatever the equivalent in this pseudocode is), or `i` is assigned `null` and `j` is assigned `1`. The former is how the equivalent expression `i, j = 1` would be interpreted in Ruby (`i == 1; j == nil`), for example, the latter is how `let i, j = 1;` would be interpreted in ECMAScript (`i === undefined; j === 1;`). Which one of the two is the intended meaning, only the author can say.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're still ignoring the context. If this is in fact an algorithm for generating Fibonacci numbers, we know exactly what i and j need to be initialised to. Even without that, we can rule out a deliberate assignment of null, because it would make the use of i+j a few lines later meaningless. I mean, it could mean "set i to the string ','" but Occam's razor suggests this is a commonly illustrated algorithm, using a straightforward integer addition, and that i and j both need to be initialised to 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming this is the algorithm for a Fibonacci number generator, it represents *simultaneous/parallel assignment*; the comma is not separating two statements, but two operands to the `<-` operator.

In `i, j <- 1`, both i and j are set to 1; it's just shorthand for `i <- 1` and `j <- 1`, which could happen in any order.

In `i,j ← j,i + j`, it means `i <- j` and *simultaneously* `j <- i+j`. It's necessary for both to happen at once, because you need to use the *original* values of both variables.

In a language without that facility, you'd have to introduce a temporary variable:

```
i2 <- i
i <- j
j <- i2 + j
```

or

```
j2 <- j
j <- i + j
i <- j2
```

This may be based on a real language with this syntax, or it may just be a convenience for the algorithms being discussed. For instance, sort algorithms will often be written in a pseudocode with a "swap" operator of some sort, rather than the full set of instructions needed in a particular language, in order to focus on the most relevant details.

Answer (score 3):

It most likely is a **tuple assignment**, i.e. assigning multiple values on the right to multiple variables on the left, with a shortcut to have only one value on the right which will be assigned to all variables. so

```
i,j ← 1
```

is the same as

```
i ← 1
j ← 1
```

And

```
i,j ← j,i + j
```

is a bit more complicated because it changes a variable it also uses, but the same as

```
tmp ← i + j
i ← j 
j ← tmp
```